# Finding an access violation in an optimized build, that does not show up in debug build (gcc)

Tags: c++, debugging, optimization

I have (probably quite common) issue that my code crashes with:

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "BaumIteration_OneDimensionCase": memory access violation at address: 0xfffffff8: no mapping at fault address
```

for an optimized build (-O3 in gcc under Linux), but works fine in a debug build. I tried to debug the release build, but it just doesn't give any useful information. What are the standard techniques to solve this issue?

In some other question someone suggested using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). How do I use it in this particular circumstances (if this is the right way forward anyways...)?

Comment: Have you tried gcc -O3 -g?  It may not generate the same code, but it could be a good starting point for tracking down the problem.  Or it could be a compiler bug.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Acually, now that I think about it, sounds like maybe some UB that is gleefully optimized into a seg fault by gcc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned , there is some code bug , but it so happens that due to different code generated, memory addresses used, it does not show up in unoptimized, debug build.

Since you asked about valgrind, the specific valgrind tool you should use is memcheck. It does a run time analysis of the code. It sure would help to find any possible errors or warnings in heap errors like memory leaks, array overbound access(Read/write), double frees ...

If you are on Linux platform , this is how to run your binary under valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck  --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --log-file=valgrind-log.txt -v --track-origins=yes <your binary file>
```

Read more about valgrind memcheck [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html).

Also if possible and if you use g++ to build , add these compiler options to your build process:

```
-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wuninitialized
```

Analyze the errors/warnings thrown by g++. It might show possible cause of error.

Goodluck debugging!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem that exists even in the debug build, but due to memory layout and what is being corrupted, it probably doesn't show up. As start point look at all the dynamic allocations, frees, arrays, pointers, uninitialized variable!

If i face this problem I will reduce the code size step by step to see if the problem exists  this way I can find the location which is causing problem!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Intel Inspector which has similar capabilities to Valgrind. It comes with parallel studio and is really good at tracking memory errors down and pointing right to the problems.

If you're working on the cheap that may be no help but we all use the intel compiler where I work so it was a dream to save a bunch of time vs trying to hunt this down otherwise